# Using repeater in html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db_conn %>" ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [slides]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<ul class="slides-container">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li><asp:Image ID="Image7" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PicName") %>'/></li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to display as many images as are stored in database but it's not working can u help me??

Comment: What is not working? What is the error message you get?

Comment: it doesn't display anything it loads other parts of the website but not this images

Comment: Could you please check what html source code render in browser?

Comment: Click `view source` on your page. Do you see any `<li>` tags? If so, there maybe something wrong with your image url. If you don't see any, your repeater is not returning anything, and it is most likely a database issue.

Comment: Does your data source actually return `PicName`.

Comment: page source says that it returns picname so I'll try to find my mistake in another part of my code